# How to get local time of different timezone in Postman?

Tags: postman, moment-timezone, postman-testcase

I want to get local time of Rome time zone. Didn't find any details on how to use moment sandbox built-in library in **postman** documentation here [postman_sandbox_api_reference](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/)

what I have tried so far

```js
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().tz(environment.TimeZone).format());
```

error it throws -  `TypeError | moment(...).tz is not a function`

another attempt-

```js
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
console.log(moment().tz(environment.TimeZone).format());
```

error it throws - `Error | Cannot find module 'moment-timezone'`

Where I'm going wrong? can anyone point me in right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postman only has the `moment` library built-in and not `moment-timezone`.

If what you're doing isn't part of the `moment` docs, it's not going to work.

https://momentjs.com/docs/

As a workaround to get the data, you could use a simple 3rd party API.

Making a request to this endpoint would get you some timezone data that you could use.

`http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Rome`

This could be added to the `pm.sendRequest()` in the `pre-request script` to fetch the data you require and use this in another request.

```js
pm.sendRequest("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Rome", function (err, res) {
    pm.globals.set("localTimeRome", res.json().datetime);
});
```

Comment: thank you :)  for mentioning work around, it worked and solved problem

Comment: This has the issue of returning an error page when worltime.org is under high load.

Comment: The workaround is just a suggestion and not the defacto solution  I'm sure there are other APIs out there that do a similar job.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can write a simple function to get local time in other time zones only with `moment`:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const TimeZoneUTCOffsetMapping = {
  'America/Chicago': -6,
  'Europe/Rome': 2,
  'Asia/Shanghai': 8,
  ...
};

const LocalUTCOffset = 8;

function getMomentDisplayInTimeZone(momentObj, timeZone) {
  let timeZoneUTCOffset = TimeZoneUTCOffsetMapping[timeZone];
  if (timeZoneUTCOffset === undefined) {
    throw new Error('No time zone matched');
  }

  return momentObj.add(timeZoneUTCOffset - LocalUTCOffset, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss');
}

console.log(getMomentDisplayInTimeZone(moment(), 'Europe/Rome'));
```

Comment: +1 yes this i thought initially, but use case is we don't know which time zone will come as input, anyway thanks for another workaround will definitely try if i need to

Comment: I think this doesn't respect switching to daylight saving time.